# Performance Comparison of Passing Arrays in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

In C# (and presumably in VB.NET) there are three ways to pass constant-value arrays to a function, namely:

```
byte[] buffer = {0};
someFunction(buffer);
```

---

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[] {0};
someFunction(buffer);
```

---

```
someFunction(new byte[] {0});
```

Whereas simple typecasting an array declarator is invalid syntax:

```
someFunction((byte[]) {0});
```

**Question:**

What are the performance difference between the three working methods - in terms of CPU usage, memory allocation, and overall program size? Does the use of the `new` keyword have any effect on RAM usage or allocation, especially in cases where the declared variable falls out of scope immedately after the function call?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
byte[] buffer = {0};
```

is simply a syntactic shortcut for

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[] {0};
```

and

```
someFunction(new byte[] {0});
```

is simply a syntactic shortcut for

```
byte[] some_tmp_variable_1 = new byte[] {0};
someFunction(some_tmp_variable_1);
```

So, as the others have concluded, you are not in fact passing the array to the method in different ways – **you are always performing the exact same operation:** All three pieces of code allocate local stack storage for a reference, all three perform a heap allocation via `new` and initialise the array memory with the provided value. Lastly, all pass the array reference to the method by value.

Comment: Your last comment is very interesting. I haven't thought about how memory allocation in .NET works before, but recall from my C++ days that there are very big differences between when the `new` keyword was used in declarations vs. when constant-value objects are hard-coded. Interesting to see the .net / CLR does not make this distinction.

Comment: @nicholas Be aware that the rules in C++ changed as well with C++11 and the introduction of uniform initialisers.

Comment: @nicholas: FYI,  in C#, "new" on a class or struct does not mean that memory is being allocated from the heap. It means that memory is being *initialized* by *invoking a constructor*. Where the memory is allocated is an implementation detail. In your example though, new-ing an array always allocates the storage from the heap. Array initializers are, as Konrad correctly points out, just a way of eliding the "new" for the sake of compactness.

Answer (score 9):

All of these valid methods will pass an array exactly the same way.  You demonstrate three ways to legally declare and initialize an array, and each time you pass that array to another method.

> someFunction((byte[]) {0});

is simply not a valid declaration syntax.

Comment: So there is no additional overhead in the first two examples, i.e., adding the `new` keyword?

Comment: @nicholas: No.  You go through the same initialization steps as if you had declared the variable in class scope.  Note that the variable does have different scope, which will affect when it is eligible for garbage collection.

Answer (score 3):

Besides the last example, your compiler will change all 3 first examples to the same code.

Answer (score 2):

`someFunction((byte[]) {0});` is just plain wrong syntax, all others all the same, only difference here is scope of your `buffer` variable.

There is no overhead.

Answer (score 1):

The three first ones are exactly the same once compiled.

The fourth one is incorrect.